# Adding pagination to a complex query

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have spent days trying to make this work. I have a book database. I have a function file called getBooks.

```
    function getBooks($limit = 10000, $sortBy = 'tblAuthor.LastName' ,  $direction='ASC', $where=1){
$db = connect();
$fields = array('tblBook.Title', 'tblAuthor.FirstName', 'tblAuthor.LastName', 'tblCategory.Category');
$format = 'Select '. implode(', ', $fields) .' FROM tblAuthor INNER JOIN (tblBook INNER JOIN tblCategory ON tblBook.CatID=tblCategory.CatID) ON tblBook.AuthorID=tblAuthor.AuthorID where %1$s ORDER BY %2$s %3$s LIMIT %4$s ';
$query = sprintf($format, $where, $sortBy, $direction, $limit);
$escapedQuery = stripslashes($db->realEscape($query));  
$db->runQuery($escapedQuery);
if($db->hasErrors()){
    print_r($db->getErrors());
    echo('<br /><br />Exiting the script.');
    die();
}
$results = $db->fillResultset();
close($db);
return $results;
```

}//end getbooks
?>

That is then called to library which handles the rest of it.

```
    <?php
    // include header
    include ("header.php");
    include_once('bookFunctions.php');
    $books=getBooks();
    $myName = "My Books";
    ?>   
   <div id="content">
   <?php if (count($books)){
   ?>
   <table class="books"> 
  <tr>
     <th>Book Title</th>
     <th>Author's Last Name</th>
     <th>Author's First Name</th>
     <th>Genre</th>
  </tr>
   <?php
    foreach($books as $book) 
        {
            echo "<tr>";//start the row

            //echo out each cell    
            echo "<td>" . $book['Title'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $book['LastName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $book['FirstName'] . "</td>";             
            echo "<td>" . $book['Category'] . "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";//end the row
        }
    ?>
```

I've tried all kinds of pagination scripts and tuts but I just can't figure out where to insert it into my query. The latest one I'm struggling with is this one: http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-pagination/
I know there must be some way to do this. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are only passing one parameter to limit -> for pagination you want to `LIMIT start,length` e.g `LIMIT 0,10` for the first page.  Reference documentation is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: I had a limit in there and it nicely shortened my database output but because I don't know where to insert the pagination thing, it had no pages. So I set it back to the original.

Answer (score 1):

If page 1 and 10 items per page your limit clase would be `LIMIT 0, 10`. That is offset 0 and length 10.

```
+------+--------+
| Page | Offset |
+------+--------+
|  1   |    0   |
|  2   |   10   |
|  3   |   20   |
+------+--------+
```

The pattern here is offset = (page - 1) * items_per_page.

```
<?php

$num_per_page = 10;

$page = intval($REQUEST['page']);
$offset = ($page - 1) * $num_per_page;

$sql_limit = "LIMIT $offset, $num_per_page";
```

One approach would be to modify your function prototype to include params for page and num_per page -

```
function getBooks($sortBy = 'tblAuthor.LastName',  $direction='ASC', $where = 1, $page = 1, $num_per_page = 10) {
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $num_per_page;
    $db = connect(); 
    $fields = array('tblBook.Title', 'tblAuthor.FirstName', 'tblAuthor.LastName', 'tblCategory.Category'); 
    $format = 'Select '. implode(', ', $fields) .' FROM tblAuthor INNER JOIN (tblBook INNER JOIN tblCategory ON tblBook.CatID=tblCategory.CatID) ON tblBook.AuthorID=tblAuthor.AuthorID where %1$s ORDER BY %2$s %3$s LIMIT %4$d, %5$d '; 
    $query = sprintf($format, $where, $sortBy, $direction, $offset, $num_per_page);
```

And then modify your call to getBooks -

```
$books=getBooks('tblAuthor.LastName', 'ASC', null, intval($_REQUEST['page']), 10);
```